# Hide A Row with Certain Text (Modify CODE) - Google Apps Script / Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the below script that can delete a row with certain text, but could it hide a row with certain text.

```
function DeleteAnyNO() {
// This Code will delete any "NO" in Column C.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
sheet.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('HOLDING'), true);
var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
var values = rows.getValues();
var rowsDeleted = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var row = values[i];
if (row[2] == 'NO') {
sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
rowsDeleted++;
}
}
};
```

So in the above code, could you modify to hide all "NO" instead of delteting ?

As Always - Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, how about the following modification?

From:

```
sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
rowsDeleted++;
```

To:

```
sheet.hideRow(sheet.getRange("A" + (i + 1)));
```

- In this case, in your script, `sheet` is Spreadsheet object. So I used `hideRow()` in Class Spreadsheet.
- Also in this case, `var rowsDeleted = 0;` is not used.

#### Reference:

- [hideRow(row) of Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#hideRow(Range))

If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Tanaike - if you come to Australia let me buy you a beer !!. I do appreciate your help and this massive Inventory system I am building for the Charity that I work for. Thank you

Comment: @Tom Sawkins Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the `rowId`, you can use `hideRows` method to hide that particular row in the Google Sheet.

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function hideRow(rowIndex) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().hideRows(rowIndex);

};
```

Comment: Thanks also Amit. I do appreciate your help.